# Right to left support for MarkdownTextBlock in uwp

Tags: uwp, windows-community-toolkit

I'm working on an Instagram unofficial client for UWP and using Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.MarkdownTextBlock for captions and some other things.
Everything is going very well in English texts but when text is in an RTL language like Persian it uses LTR for them too. 
Unfortunately, MarkdownTextBlock doesn't have a `TextAlignment` property and also I wasn't able to find a markdown to show text in Right to left. 
Is there any way for it?

UWP Target Platform: Windows 10 Version 1803 (Build 17134)
Minimum version; Anniversary Update (Build 14393)
Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls: V4.0 (Because I want to support Windows 10 Mobile it's not possible to use V5.0)

Thank you

Comment: You will need to raise this directly in Github https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/issues

Comment: By the way, MarkdownTextBlock's source code is also listed on Github. You can see that it is a high customized control, it's render and behavior is all wrote by code behind. If you need right the left behavior, you may also try to check the souce code there and see if you can modify anything

Comment: @BarryWang-MSFT yes you're right. But as I'm using the ```Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls``` NuGet in my project so I prefer not to add the same codes once again, However because of the New versions of ```Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls``` don't support 14393 seems I have to do it. No way. Anyway, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have [logged an issue](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/issues/2642) on github as well as a [fix for the issue](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/pull/2643). When all of the kinks are worked out it will be released in the next version.

UPDATE: Fix has been merged. Feel free to take the source and use in your app or wait until the next version is released.

Comment: Fix has been merged

Comment: Yes, I saw that they added some commits for it. Again thanks to you bro :)